# IOS build disappeared from TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native-ios, testflight

I created 2 `IOS` builds today, in `Xcode` it says that there were successfully uploaded, however, when I was checking `TestFlight`, these builds appeared for 10 seconds with the status Processing, and after that builds disappeared and never showed up again. I have created many builds before for this app, the latest was few days ago, I have never seen such behavior. What can be the problem?

I didn't receive any emails or didn't receive any errors.

[image]

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: I contacted Apple support about this. I was told that they had "internal errors" on the builds and I needed to increment the build number and upload again, which worked.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, when it happened, it sent a message to the email associated with the account alerting that there was some missing data on info.plist.

Basically, the application appears there for a while, then it silently dissapears, and an error message is sent to the aforementioned email.

So, basically, if anyone else happens to have this problem, remember to take a look at the email account associated with the Apple account.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was the scenario that Haroldo_OK described. I received a mail that said my application have some missing dependencies from Info.plist. Check your mail in order to see what dependecies are missing from your Info.plist file or what others problems may have appeard during build.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same thing today. I uploaded 3 builds earlier today, all of which said "processing" for a few seconds and then disappeared. I nor the team agent have received any emails. The only thing I can think of is Apple is having technical difficulties on their side today.  It's been around 8 hrs since I uploaded the first build and I still see nothing in the TestFlight activity section.

Answer (score 0):

I updated IOS in my Mac to the latest version, and also changed app version to the new one 1.0.21, not just build version, after that new build appeared in TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Mine is a flutter application I deleted my iOS folder due to some setting issue happened for version controlling. I re-create the folder and all the settings were lost in my **info.plist** file.

I've got a backup of my file and replaced it with the new one and it completely works fine.